Is there any way for a Mleccha to become an Arya?
In Manusmriti and various other texts which outlines Dharma it mentions how when Arya's conquer Mleccha land and the Brahminas enter they make the land pure and hence while the people are impure the land is considered Aryavrata. My question is whether a mleccha or barbaric forgeiner can become an Arya not nessecarily a Dvija, but a Sudra. Here is one of my sources, History Video on Mlecchas

It is possible by Bhakti. Through initiation, anyone can be transformed to an Aryan and equal in status to a Brahmana, what to speak of becoming a Shudra.

yathā kāñcanatām yāti kāmsyam rasa-vidhānataḥ tathā dīkṣā-vidhānena
dvijatvam jāyate nṛṇām
"As bell metal, when mixed with mercury, is transformed to gold, a
person, even though not golden pure, can be transformed into a
brāhmaṇa, or dvija, simply by the initiation process."
(Hari-bhakti-vilāsa 2.12)

According to Nārada Muni,

yasya yal lakṣaṇam proktam pumso varṇābhivyañjakam yad anyatrāpi
dṛśyeta tat tenaiva vinirdiśet
If one shows the symptoms of being a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, vaiśya or
śūdra, as described above, even if he has appeared in a different
class, he should be accepted according to those symptoms of
classification (Shrimad Bhagavatam 7.11.35)

As per Hari Bhakti Subhodaya,

bhagavad-bhakti-hīnasya jātiḥ śāstram japas tapaḥ aprāṇasyaiva dehasya
maṇḍanam loka-rañjanam
"If one is born in a high family like that of a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya or
vaiśya but is not a devotee of the Lord, all his good qualifications
as a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya or vaiśya are null and void. Indeed, they are
considered decorations of a dead body."

As per Prahalada, a chandala (lower than Mleccha) who has dedicated everything to Lord Hari is greater than the qualified Brahmana averse to Lord Hari.

viprād dvi-ṣaḍ-guṇa-yutād aravinda-nābha- pādāravinda-vimukhāt
śvapacam variṣṭham manye tad-arpita-mano-vacanehitārtha- prāṇam punāti
sa kulam na tu bhūrimānaḥ
If a brāhmaṇa has all twelve of the brahminical qualifications [as
they are stated in the book called Sanat-sujāta] but is not a devotee
and is averse to the lotus feet of the Lord, he is certainly lower
than a devotee who is a dog-eater but who has dedicated
everything—mind, words, activities, wealth and life—to the Supreme
Lord. Such a devotee is better than such a brāhmaṇa because the
devotee can purify his whole family, whereas the so-called brāhmaṇa in
a position of false prestige cannot purify even himself (Shrimad Bhagavatam 7.9.10).

